# Swagger UI + OpenAPI rendering image with full width

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

I'm using `Python + Flask + Connexion + Swagger + OpenAPI`.

I have this `OpenAPI` file:

[image]

When I execute it, it renders the image properly.

**My problem is:** The image gets rendered too big because there is a CSS class that is attached to the image: `full-width`. Is there anyway to say the `Swagger UI` not to add that class?

Bear in mind that I'm using: `openapi: 3.0.1`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by overwriting the `Swagger-UI / CSS` file.

If as me you are using: `Python + Flask + Connexion + Swagger + OpenAPI` then you can define a new route with the same path as the file: `swagger-ui.css` and serve it with the original content but with the change below. That makes the trick.

```
...
.swagger-ui img.full-width {
    /* width: 100% */
}
...
```

Comment: Alternatively, add `<style>.swagger-ui img.full-width {width: auto !important;}</style>` in the `<head>` section of your Swagger UI `index.html` page.

Answer (score 0):

This styling issue [was fixed](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/pull/7495) in Swagger UI v. 3.52.3.